# Как сверстать блок с изображением на фоне и пинами?

Tags: bootstrap, img

Есть подобный блок. Пины на изображении должны быть зафиксированы и меняться при ховере, вопрос стоит в том, как сверстать правильно подобные вещи? В мобильный версии этого блока нет, но как это сверстать и зафиксировать до максимально уменьшаемого размера? На экране в 1920 это сделать можно и не составит проблем в "подогнать" по пикселям, но всё поползет при уменьшении. Есть идеи? Верстать буду по сетке бутстрап 4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не уверен что такие вещи стоит делать для мобильных версий

Comment: Я об этом и написал, но как сделать, чтобы верстка не ехала при уменьшении экрана и его растягивании?